# Swift - Increasing height of alert view

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I am adding some labels and a text field to alert controller, but that doesn't automatically increase the height of the alert. If I just add a bunch of text fields to alert controller, then it automatically increases height of the alert view.

How do I increase the height of alert with labels and text field on it?

**Code with labels and text field:**

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert title", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

let confirmLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: 50, width: 270, height:16))
confirmLabel.textAlignment = .left
confirmLabel.text = "Confirm details"
confirmLabel.textColor = UIColor(rgb: 0x6E6E6E)
confirmLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0, weight: .medium)
alertController.view.addSubview(confirmLabel)
confirmLabel.isHidden = false

alertController.addTextField { (textField) -> Void in
     textField.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 68, width: 270, height:16)
     textField.placeholder = "Enter text"
     textField.keyboardType = .default
     textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}

let dateTimeLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: 84, width: 270, height:16))
dateTimeLabel.textAlignment = .left
dateTimeLabel.text = "Confirm details 1 "
dateTimeLabel.textColor = UIColor(rgb: 0x6E6E6E)
dateTimeLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0, weight: .medium)
alertController.view.addSubview(dateTimeLabel)
dateTimeLabel.isHidden = false

let locationLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: 100, width: 270, height:16))
locationLabel.textAlignment = .left
locationLabel.text = "Confirm details 2"
locationLabel.textColor = UIColor(rgb: 0x6E6E6E)
locationLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14.0, weight: .medium)
alertController.view.addSubview(locationLabel)
locationLabel.isHidden = false

let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { alert -> Void in
    let firstTextField = alertController.textFields![0] as UITextField
})

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertAction.Style.destructive, handler: {(action : UIAlertAction!) -> Void in })

alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
alertController.addAction(saveAction)

if let textFields = alertController.textFields {
   if textFields.count > 0, let titleTextField = textFields[0] as? UITextField {
       titleTextField.superview?.superview?.subviews[0].removeFromSuperview()
       titleTextField.superview?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
}
        
alertController.view.layoutSubviews()

if let topVC = UIApplication.shared.topMostViewController() {
   topVC.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

[image]

Edit: Added a height constraint and that fixed my problem.

```
let constraintHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(
   item: alertController.view!, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute:
   NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 250)
alertController.view.addConstraint(constraintHeight)
```

Comment: I added a height constraint and that worked:

        let constraintHeight = NSLayoutConstraint(
           item: alertController.view!, attribute: NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute:
           NSLayoutConstraint.Attribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 250)
        alertController.view.addConstraint(constraintHeight)

Comment: Heads up: It might work with your custom constraint now, but there's no guarantee that this will work in future versions of iOS. You really shouldn't add subviews to the alert this way, it's prone to breaking.

Comment: @Rengers - Thanks for the heads up! Any idea, what's the best way to add labels to alerts? For text field, AlertController already has a API, called 'addTextField', but am not finding anything for label in it. 

And although I was able to solve the height issue, vertical alignment of text field is still an issue which I will be asking in a separate post.

Comment: `UIAlertController` does not provide an API for adding labels. If you really want to do a custom layout like that, you should probably create an entirely custom view. That's quite a bit more work though.

Comment: Thanks @Rengers! I am actually working on a custom view now. I realized adjusting all the labels and text field and size of alert view was more difficult without constraints.